# How to inspect elements using Firebug while building a custom addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

I am building a custom firefox addon,But unlike chrome where I can inspect the HTML within the extension I cannot do the same for FF.

I need to style the HTML. Any clues on how I can go about this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. Do you ask for how to access the website content from within your extension?

Comment: I need to inspect the HTML structure of my addon. I can inspect it in chrome by right click + inspect. Cannot do the same for FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the XUL and HTML structure of your add-on using [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/).

To do so do the following:

1. Start your extension and do all the steps until you want to inspect the HTML
2. Open DOM Inspector via the *Firefox Menu > Web Developer > DOM Inspector*
3. Select the document of your extension via *File > Inspect Content Document* or *File > Inspect Chrome Document*

Then you'll see the structure and should be able to inspect any element inside of it via the inspector tool, which is accessible via the button in the upper right corner and works similar to the one in Firebug by clicking on any element inside your extension.

This tool is actually used by the Firebug Working Group to inspect the HTML structures inside Firebug.